# Angular 2 how use images in component

Tags: angular

Help me please! How to use images in components.
It does not work in production .
How to add a production build of this picture?
How to write the URL in the src?

Comment: start with **"./"**

Comment: The same way your would do if you were not using angular: by using the path (absolute or relative) to the image. Since you didn't post any detail, that's really all I can say.

Comment: <img src="./assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo"> It does not work :(

Comment: That is a relative path. What is the absolute path of the image on the server, and what's the path (i.e. the content of the address bar of your browser) of the page where these images should be displayed? Why don't you just use an absolute path, which would be valid whatever the current page URL is?

Comment: but it works in development (http://localhost:4200/)   How to specify correct path to work in production ?

Comment: Answering the questions I ask might be a good first step.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var require: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-logo',
  templateUrl: './logo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logo.component.scss']
})
export class LogoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  public heroImageUrl = require("./images/logo_OK.png");

}
```